# How to use hive merge into syntax?

Tags: merge, hive

This is my two hive tables and the merge into sql:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
ID int,
TranValue string,
last_update_user string)
CLUSTERED BY (ID) into 5 buckets 
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

CREATE TABLE merge_source(
ID int,
TranValue string,
tran_date string);

sql1:
MERGE INTO transactions AS T 
USING merge_source AS S
ON T.ID = S.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TranValue = S.TranValue, last_update_user = 'merge_update'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (S.ID, S.TranValue, 'merge_insert','123');

sql2:
MERGE INTO transactions AS T 
USING merge_source AS S
ON T.ID = S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (S.ID, S.TranValue, 'merge_insert','123');

sql3:
MERGE INTO transactions AS T 
USING merge_source AS S
ON T.ID = S.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TranValue = S.TranValue, last_update_user = 'merge_update';
```

sql2 and sql3 is ok, but sql1 return code 2 error and this is the error infomation:

```
ERROR [main] mr.MapredLocalTask: Hive Runtime Error: Map local work failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.initialize(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:57) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinUtil.getObjectInspectorsFromEvaluators(JoinUtil.java:91) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.HashTableSinkOperator.initializeOp(HashTableSinkOperator.java:153) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:366) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:556) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:508) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.initializeOperators(MapredLocalTask.java:508) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.startForward(MapredLocalTask.java:411) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.executeInProcess(MapredLocalTask.java:391) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:764) ~[hive-exec-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar:?]
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

set hive.auto.convert.join=false;